# How do REST URIs work internally?

Tags: android, ios, api, rest

I'm trying to create a REST API to interact with a MySQL database. I want to use this API to access the database from an Android or iOS device without (obviously) exposing the database directly through the application. But I'm having problems wrapping my head around a key aspect about REST and the implementation of an API designed on its principles.

I understand the concepts of REST from the theory stand point. What I've been struggling for days trying to grasp is **how a REST URI maps to something located on a database server.**

If I make a GET request to a server for a resource with a given URI, say http://www.example.com/resource, internally, where does this go to on the server? The way I understand it, is that it goes to the root directory, then to the "resource" directory. From there it returns all the files within that "resource" directory. I'm simply confused because the resource is located on the database server and not the server where the API is being called from. Does the resource path/hierarchy represent actual directories on the server or is it an abstraction of the resource? If the latter, then what do I do with that abstracted resource name to make it map to a table or row in a database? It's been frustrating not being able to find concrete implementation examples of this where I can easily understand how this URI path works internally.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. This is too open ended and asks too many questions.

Comment: I don't think this deserves downvoting. Sure, the question is vague, but it's not because of a lack of information in the question. The questioner is simply confused by the RESTful mindset and asked to have it clarified. It seems that he already did a fair amount of research before asking, without completely understanding what a RESTful API is meant to represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a framework to do a lot of the work for you, but what happens under the hood is no magic. In some way, the URIs map to some database tables. They don't refer to a certain directory structure, but try to explain a hierarchical relationship between the resources.

For example, let's say that we're modelling a university. The elements in the database are stored in one of two tables, either *Faculties* or *Courses*. The Faculties table consists of rows describing the Faculty of Law, Faculty of Medicine and so on. It has a unique *faculty_id* column and then columns to describe whatever we need. The Courses table has a unique *course_id* column and a foreign key *faculty_id* column, to tell which faculty the course belongs to.

A RESTful way of designing this API might be

- `/faculties` to get a list of all faculties, retrieved with `SELECT * FROM Faculties`
- `/faculties/2` to get the information about a certain faculty, retrieved with `SELECT * FROM Faculties WHERE faculty_id=2`
- `/faculties/2/courses` to get all the courses belonging to a certain faculty, retrieved with `SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE faculty_id=2`
- `/faculties/2/courses/15` to retrieve a certain course, if it indeed belongs to faculty 2, retrieved with `SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE faculty_id=2 AND course_id=15`

The exact implementation of this depends on the programming language (and possibly framework) that you choose, but at some point you need to make choices about how you should be able to query the database. This is not obvious. You need to plan it carefully for it to make sense!

The result from the database will of course have to be encoded in some way, typically XML or JSON (but other representations are just as fine, although maybe not as common).

Apart from this, you should also make sure to implement the four verbs correctly so that they match the SQL commands (`GET`=`SELECT`, `POST`=`INSERT`, `PUT`=`UPDATE`, `DELETE`=`DELETE`), handle encoding negotiation correctly, return proper HTTP response codes and all the other things that are expected of a RESTful API.

As a final piece of advice: If you do this neatly, it'll become *so much easier* for you to design your mobile apps. I really can't stress this enough. For example, if you on a `POST` request return the full entry as it now looks in the database, you can immediately store it on the phone with the correct ID, and you can use the same code for rendering the content as you would if it had been downloaded using a `GET` request. Also, you won't trick the user by updating prematurely, before you know whether that request was successful (mobile phones lose connection a lot).

**EDIT:** To answer your question in the comments: Creating an API can be seen as a form of art, and should probably not involve any coding in the design stage. The API should be meaningful and not rely on a particular implementation (i.e. a different database choice shouldn't affect your API). Your next task will be to create ties between the human-readable structure of the API and your database (regardless of whether it's relational or something else). So yes, you will need to do some translation, but I don't see how the query string would help you. The typical structure is `api.my.website/collection/element/collection/element`. Queries can be used for filtering. You could for example write `example.com/resource?since=2012-06-01` to retrieve a subset of the elements from your 'resource' collection, but the meaning of this particular query is to retrieve something you *couldn't* express with an unique ID.

The way I understand it, you think that incoming requests must always go to separate files based on the way PHP and HTTP servers work. This is **not** the case. You can [configure your web server to route every request to a single PHP file](http://www.kavoir.com/2010/02/use-php-to-handle-all-incoming-url-requests-in-a-seo-friendly-manner.html) and then parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Depending on your choice of HTTP server your mileage might vary, but this is essentially what you want to do.

By googling I found [a list of frameworks for PHP](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/09/23/short-list-of-restful-api-frameworks-for-php/) but I don't know any of them. There are others, though, and I also recently heard someone mention [Apify](http://www.apifydoc.com/), although I can't tell you much about that either. PHP is probably one more the more common choices for implementing an API. [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), however, is a library/tool that's only designed to connect to *other* websites, as far as I know. You can certainly use [the command line version of it](http://curl.haxx.se/) to debug your API, but I don't think you'll have much use for it on the server side.

Comment: Thank you very much that was quite helpful! For a little more clarification: by the way you describe it, which is what I was thinking it meant, it seems that in some way I have to translate the URI into usable data to perform the query. So would it be something like translating my original example say http://www.example.com/resource/23 into http://www.example.com/resource?resource-id=23? If so, is that done from some language library or is it something I have to implement? I'm using PHP for the implementation and looked into cURL. Would that be something I use for that sort of thing?

Comment: @Perley: My reply was too long to fit in a comment; check the edit I made to the answer. Let me know if you need more help. Good luck!

Comment: Again thank you very much, you have been very helpful. After I had asked that, I immediately searched for the way to parse the URIs to my server and found out that I do indeed just need to take any URI of the API's form and just reroute it to a handler which parses it and turns into something meaningful for the API to use. However I wasn't sure entirely how to go about doing this. It's nice to have confirmation when you're not entirely sure. So I thank you again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with what framework you want to built the REST application from. Rails, RestEasy for java, Codeigniter, all have the basis for good REST routing capabilities. 
This includes abstracting URL's from the underlining resource either from database or even business processes. They accomplish this using URL mapping, or creating a Facade for abstractions.
Generally REST does not really differ from tradational GET/PUT/POST with query parameters. Infact Apache URL rewrites usually are used to support REST style routing.  I recommend you should pick up one of the frameworks and study how they implement this functions. Rails i thing has significant strength among other frameworks.

Comment: This sort of answers my question. The framework in place is Drupal (which I did not choose). So is it just the practice to build the service around the framework using whatever support they have for REST (or SOAP for that matter)? I'm sorry if this is all a bunch of stupid question as nitty gritty wed development is new to me. I just like understanding how things work entirely rather than accepting them at face value.